# Java StringBuilder doesn't append whole InputStream

Tags: java, eclipse, stringbuilder

I have a weird error in my code. I'm trying to read some characters from `InputStreamReader` using char buffer and appending it to `StringBuilder`.

The snippet is here:

```
char[] buffer = new char[4096];
int numRead = 0;
webResource = new StringBuilder("");
while ( (numRead = reader.read(buffer, 0, 4096)) != -1 )
            {
                System.out.println("Capacity before: "+webResource.capacity());
                webResource.append(buffer, 0, numRead);
                System.out.println("Capacity after: "+webResource.capacity());
            }
```

The `System.out.println()` is only for debug purpose.

I'm trying to read `InputStream` that have 147 781 chars. First two times in while cycle is everything ok, I read characters into buffer and then it is appended to `webResource (StringBuilder)`.

But at the third iteration I read to buffer 4096 characters but only 1446 characters are appended to `webResource (StringBuilder)`.

I've been debugging the code in Eclipse and while watching variable `webResource` I find out that, after third iteration (after appendding 1446 characters) the content of variable simply ends with "..." and no new characters are added in next iterations.

Weird thing also is, that `webResource.count` is incementing properly (after four interations its value is 16 384, and so on).

Pleas can anyone help? I really do not see where is the problem of why I can't append whole `inputstream` to `StringBuilder`, I can only append the first 9 638 characters.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's hard to tell what's going wrong here. Try posting a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) with the source of the `InputStream` for us to test.

Comment: As a side note, why not just use: [`IOUtils.toString()`](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-2.0/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#toString(java.io.InputStream,%20java.lang.String))?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be misinterpreting what you see in the debugger.  The debugger is not showing you the whole content of the stringbuilder because it's too long. but it's all there.,